# Menu on wordpress changing from horizontal to vertical

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have multiple websites replicating same template/content for different locations but for some reason only one of the websites is having an issue on the menu changing how it displays.

I've already tried deleting and adding again, as well as copying menu from one to the other but for some reason it keeps changing .

You can see an example of a good working website

[www.faceup-romanorte.com](http://www.faceup-romanorte.com)

and example of the website having the issue
[www.faceup-cancun.com](http://www.faceup-cancun.com)

```js
<div data-elementor-type="header" data-elementor-id="178" class="elementor elementor-178 elementor-location-header" data-elementor-post-type="elementor_library">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-32e6cb8 e-con-full e-flex e-con e-parent" data-id="32e6cb8" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;motion_fx_motion_fx_scrolling&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;]}" data-core-v316-plus="true">
        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c8d0c33 e-con-full e-flex e-con e-child animated fadeIn" data-id="c8d0c33" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;animation&quot;:&quot;fadeIn&quot;,&quot;animation_delay&quot;:200}">
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-aaadcca de_scroll_animation_no elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="aaadcca" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <style>/*! elementor - v3.20.0 - 26-03-2024 */
.elementor-widget-image{text-align:center}.elementor-widget-image a{display:inline-block}.elementor-widget-image a img[src$=".svg"]{width:48px}.elementor-widget-image img{vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block}</style>                                          <a href="https://faceup-romanorte.com/">
                            <img width="298" height="56" src="https://faceup-cancun.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/cropped-logo_white-1.png" class="elementor-animation-float attachment-large size-large wp-image-2941" alt="" srcset="https://faceup-cancun.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/cropped-logo_white-1.png 298w, https://faceup-cancun.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/cropped-logo_white-1-18x3.png 18w" sizes="(max-width: 298px) 100vw, 298px">                                </a>
                                                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d452fa9 e-con-full e-flex e-con e-child" data-id="d452fa9" data-element_type="container">
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-842b443 elementor-nav-menu__align-center elementor-nav-menu--dropdown-mobile elementor-nav-menu--stretch elementor-nav-menu__text-align-aside elementor-nav-menu--toggle elementor-nav-menu--burger de_scroll_animation_no elementor-widget elementor-widget-nav-menu" data-id="842b443" data-element_type="widget" data-settings="{&quot;full_width&quot;:&quot;stretch&quot;,&quot;layout&quot;:&quot;horizontal&quot;,&quot;submenu_icon&quot;:{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;<i class=\&quot;fas fa-caret-down\&quot;><\/i>&quot;,&quot;library&quot;:&quot;fa-solid&quot;},&quot;toggle&quot;:&quot;burger&quot;}" data-widget_type="nav-menu.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://faceup-cancun.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/css/widget-nav-menu.min.css">         <nav class="elementor-nav-menu--main elementor-nav-menu__container elementor-nav-menu--layout-horizontal e--pointer-underline e--animation-fade">
                <ul id="menu-1-842b443" class="elementor-nav-menu" data-smartmenus-id="171167751282493"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1689"><a href="https://faceup-cancun.com/tratamientos-de-medicina-estetica/" class="elementor-item">Servicios</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1797"><a href="https://faceup-cancun.com/skincare-products/" class="elementor-item">Skincare Products</a></li>
<li class="trp-language-switcher-container menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-language_switcher menu-item-1560"><a href="https://faceup-cancun.com/en/?elementor_library=elementor-header-178&amp;preview_id=178&amp;preview_nonce=07d2e17f26&amp;preview=true" class="elementor-item elementor-item-anchor"><span data-no-translation=""><img class="trp-flag-image" src="https://faceup-cancun.com/wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/assets/images/flags/en_US.png" width="18" height="12" alt="en_US" title="English"></span></a></li>
</ul>           </nav>
                    <div class="elementor-menu-toggle" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Alternar menú" aria-expanded="false">
            <i aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" class="elementor-menu-toggle__icon--open eicon-menu-bar"></i><i aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" class="elementor-menu-toggle__icon--close eicon-close"></i>            <span class="elementor-screen-only">Menú</span>
        </div>
                    <nav class="elementor-nav-menu--dropdown elementor-nav-menu__container" aria-hidden="true" style="top: 25px; width: 1132px; left: -766.703px;">
                <ul id="menu-2-842b443" class="elementor-nav-menu" data-smartmenus-id="17116775128240054"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1689"><a href="https://faceup-cancun.com/tratamientos-de-medicina-estetica/" class="elementor-item" tabindex="-1">Servicios</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1797"><a href="https://faceup-cancun.com/skincare-products/" class="elementor-item" tabindex="-1">Skincare Products</a></li>
<li class="trp-language-switcher-container menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-language_switcher menu-item-1560"><a href="https://faceup-cancun.com/en/?elementor_library=elementor-header-178&amp;preview_id=178&amp;preview_nonce=07d2e17f26&amp;preview=true" class="elementor-item elementor-item-anchor" tabindex="-1"><span data-no-translation=""><img class="trp-flag-image" src="https://faceup-cancun.com/wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/assets/images/flags/en_US.png" width="18" height="12" alt="en_US" title="English"></span></a></li>
</ul>           </nav>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3898e4d e-con-full elementor-hidden-mobile e-flex e-con e-child" data-id="3898e4d" data-element_type="container">
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c8dd9a7 elementor-widget__width-auto de_scroll_animation_no elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="c8dd9a7" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="button.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
            <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-sm" href="https://faceup.site.agendapro.com/mx/sucursal/99881" id="cta-book-landing-marketing">
                        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">RESERVAR</span>
        </span>
                    </a>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

I did not changing any css or any custom code to that menu but the issue seems to be persistent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: this solved the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDwGM2HPhd0

Answer (score -1):

Seems like this was rather an elementor issue. This solved the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDwGM2HPhd0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).